# How to put Imageview Below Listview in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I Have a Layout for my Activity,this layout consists a lot of widgets.
in my activity data loaded from webservice in Listview.
when  listview is Adapted and fill All data. imagview was Invisible
But I want show Imageview Below Listview when data Loaded.

My code in  activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel_index"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f8f8f8"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115sp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corener_edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/center"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:textColor="#44e1f4" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="135sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25sp"
        android:background="@drawable/header" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/digi_logo"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:background="#2391a2"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_app"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:text="@string/txt_name"
            android:textColor="#1e7c95"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_offer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lst_data"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/offers_btn"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to Resolve My Problms.thanks.

Comment: You need to change the layout_height of the List view from wrap_content to a specific value.

Comment: No a specific value is just crap for different screen sizes. Don't make that. Better is the answer below, or work with weight-values.
I would prefere the answer below ;)

Comment: @Logi24 aren't weight values only usable in the context of a linear layout?

Comment: yes, but you can switch the layout to LinearLayout. With this you can do all too.

Comment: LinearLayout Can't Work for Me.Imagview is Invisible

Answer (score 5):

What you are currently telling the layout inflater to do is place your header layout `rel_top` at the top, then place a `ListView` below it, and then place an `ImageView` below that. What you want is basically to have the `ImageView` anchored to the bottom of the display, and stretch the `ListView` between the image and the header layout.

Instead of aligning your `ImageView` below the `ListView` you should align your `ImageView` the the bottom of the screen

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_offer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/offers_btn"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

And align the `ListView` to be below `rel_top` and above the `ImageView`

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_top"
        **android:layout_above="@+id/img_offer"**
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

Comment: No.I could put Imageview bottom of screen.but show listview must be imageview show below Listview

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve then? aren't you trying to have your image appear at the bottom of the screen and have the listview above it

Comment: That's what the code above is supposed to do. what do you get when you try it?

Answer (score 2):

```
private ImageView _imgView = null;
_imgView = new ImageView(this);
_listView.addFooterView(_imgView);
```

Try this; it may be able to help you.